# How to open the mail client using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

I have an input which onClick action calls a JavaScript function. 
The problem is that I need to open the mail client with the mail address the user wrote in the form. 
I've read that I should use `<a href:mailto....></a>` but I can not use it because the user won't click on this link. 
The user will only click on the submit button, calling submit() function. 
Is it possible to add an other onClick event tho the same button?

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: Remember, not anybody has a local mail client. A lot of people only use web clients today.

Comment: You can use the mailto: link even for web clients. most of the browsers support this. See an example in this post: https://runkiss.blogspot.com/2021/07/open-default-mail-client-from-javasctipt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open an email programmatically you can use `window.location.assign` with a `mailto:` link:

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // handle the form submission (AJAX...)

    window.location.assign('mailto:foo@bar.com');
});
```

Comment: As a side note, to still submit the `form`: `setTimeout(function(){
        this.submit();
    }.bind(this));`  EDIT: in fact doesn't seem to be OP expected behaviour, so no need to submit the form

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hidden link and use jquery to 'click' it when the users presses your submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#submit-button").on("click",function() {
            window.location = document.getElementById('mail-link').href;
        });
    });
</script>

<button id="submit-button">Click me</button>

<a id="mail-link" href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com" style="display: none;"></a>
```